# XSLT same element names, give them a dynamic/iterated name

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<case>
    <name>John</name>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <name>Sarah</name>
    <name>Max</name>
</case>
```

How do can i use XLST to transform this into:

```
 <case>
    <name1>John</name1>
    <name2>Bill</name2>
    <name3>Sarah</name3>
    <name4>Max</name4>
</case>
```

The number of `name` can basically vary from 1 to 10, so i am looking for +1 iteration.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It will make for a very difficult format to process later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any possible reason why you should want to generate such ghastly XML, but if you really want to, you just need

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:element name="name{position()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```